# How to understand "Every Class object contains a reference to the ClassLoader that defined it. "?

Tags: java, class, jvm, classloader

- I know I can get a the classloader of a class by
  `xxxclass.class.getClassLoader()`, but where exactly does the `xxxclass`
  hold the reference of its classloader who defines it? 
  e.g.

  ```
  public class ClassA {    
      System.out.println("I am class A"); 
  }
  ```

  I don't see any clue of the classloader reference in `ClassA`. However,
  I can get the classloader of `ClassA` by using
  `ClassA.class.getClassLoader()`.
- How does `ClassA.class.getClassLoader()` work?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't see any clue of the classloader reference in ClassA" - where would you expect to see it? Do you understand that `ClassA.class` is a value of type `Class`, not of type `ClassA`?

Comment: `but where exactly does the xxxclass hold the reference` that is exactly the sense of OOP: the user don't need that information and is not available thru the "interface". Anyway if you are interested have a look in the [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Class.java.html), its is a native method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence as it appears in the documentation of `ClassLoader` is:

> Every [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object contains a [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader()) to the ClassLoader that defined it.

Note the two links? What they tell you is that the documentation refers to the `Class` object, not to the plain object of class `ClassA`.

Every class that you define in Java has a `Class` object associated with it, which allows you to look at that class in the meta level. That is, treat the class itself as an object, pass it as parameter, use reflection on it etc.

As you have noticed, one way to access the `Class` object is use `ClassA.class`. If you have a reference to an object of type `ClassA`:

```
ClassA myObj = new ClassA();
```

Then you can get the `Class` object using `myObj.getClass()`.

So there is no reference to the `ClassLoader` in the `myObj` object, Only in its associated `Class` object.

Now, the other link tells you how to get the reference to the `ClassLoader` object once you have a `Class` object - through the `getClassLoader()` method.

Now, if you look at the source code of the `Class` class, you will see:

```
@CallerSensitive
public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
    ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader0();
    if (cl == null)
        return null;
    SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (sm != null) {
        ClassLoader.checkClassLoaderPermission(cl, Reflection.getCallerClass());
    }
    return cl;
}
```

So it calls `getClassLoader0()` to get the class loader. Its source is:

```
native ClassLoader getClassLoader0();
```

That is, the class loader reference is actually part of the native structure of this Java class, and it is not available to see using Java language tools. Nevertheless, it exists there, and available to you through the aforesaid method.

Answer (score 1):

If you write this:

```
public class Ball {
    private Person thrower;
    public Ball(Person thrower) {
        this.thrower = thrower;
    }

    public Person getThrower() {return thrower;}
}
```

then every `Ball` object contains a reference to the `Person` that threw it, right?

Similarly, the `Class` class has something like this: (although I'm not showing how `classLoader` gets assigned)

```
public class Class {
    ... other stuff ...

    private ClassLoader classLoader;
    public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {return classLoader;}

    ... other stuff ...
}
```

and so every `Class` object has a reference to the `ClassLoader` that loaded it.

In your example, `ClassA` is not a `Class` object, so the statement doesn't apply to it. It *does* apply to `ClassA.class` which *is* a `Class` object (or refers to one at least).

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it's not so simple in this case.

<sub>(Or at least, it *was* not so simple, until a recent update)</sub>

Java is a very high-level language, and the JVM is a rather complex beast, which is (fortunately!) hiding many details that you don't want to be concerned with when using a high-level, object-oriented language.

As already pointed out in the other answers, the `Class#getClassLoader()` method delegates to a `private native` method `getClassLoader0()`. Usually, you simply don't know (and should not have to care about) what a private `native` method does.

But thanks to the open source JDK, one can trace the path of this method call (here, for a recent version of the JDK8) :

- The native `getClassLoader0` method of `Class` [is bound to `JVM_GetClassLoader`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/native/java/lang/Class.c#l59)
- The `JVM_GetClassLoader` method eventually [calls `Klass::class_loader()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#l1040)
- The `Klass::class_loader()` method only [returns the result of `ClassLoaderData::class_loader()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/oops/klass.cpp#l545)
- The `ClassLoaderData::class_loader()` method finally [returns the field that you are looking for](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/classfile/classLoaderData.hpp#l231)

---

However, note that [this has changed in a recent commit of the JDK9](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/hs-rt/hotspot/rev/fcbb13e52461): Now, the `ClassLoader` is stored as a private instance field in the `Class` class, in order to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of java.lang.Class it appears that it delegates to a native method called getClassLoader0.  So the implementation details are down to the JVM.

I'm no expert on this, but I suppose this might allow garbage collection to work by not having reference cycles in Java.